# Splitting string into strings of certain size in C

Tags: c, string

Let's say I have a string "abcd1234efgh". I want to split it into substrings of length 4, like:
abcd
1234
efgh

My C is rusty. Here's what I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){

int i,j;
char values[32]="abcd1234efgh";
char temp[10];

for(i=0;values[i]!='\0';){
   for (j=0;j<4;j++,i++){
      temp[i]=values[j];
      printf("%c\n",values[j]);
   }
printf("string temp:%s\n",temp);
}

return 0;
}
```

The output is obviously wrong because I'm not saving the index of the original string. Any tips on how to fix this? For strings with a length that is not a multiple of 4, I would like to pad the short substring with spaces.

Comment: temp need only hold 4 characters. Because right now I get the first 4 characters with every iteration. In other words, it resets and appends the same first 4 over and over. What I want is to get the first four, then the next four, etc. so that I can feed them to another buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick if you're seeking to print only:

```
int len = strlen(values);
for (int off = 0; off < len; off += 4)
    printf("%.4s\n", values+off);
```

If you want to do something else (as well) with the groups of 4, then I'd consider:

```
int len = strlen(values);
for (int off = 0; off < len; off += 4)
{
    strncpy(temp, values+off, 4);
    temp[4] = '\0';
    …do as you will with temp…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE : the code is to print in group of 4 and not break and store the string if size 4

if this is what you asked for

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
int i;
char values[32]="abcd1234efgh";
for(i=0;values[i]!='\0';)
{
    if( i % 4 == 0 ) printf("\n");
    printf("%c",values[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: One minor problem is that if the number of characters in `values` is not a multiple of 4, your output will not end with a newline.

Comment: there should not be ant problem just add a newline character after the loop ends
you were never crystal clear on the problem

Comment: I don't think so, and empirical evidence shows that my solution prints out 3 characters and a newline on the third line if the string is `"abcd1234efg"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str = "abcd1234efgh";
    size_t sub_len = 4;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    size_t n = len / sub_len;
    if(n * sub_len < len)
        n += 1;

    char temp[n][sub_len+1];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        strncpy(temp[i], str + i*sub_len, sub_len);
        temp[i][sub_len]='\0';
        printf("string temp:%s\n", temp[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){

int i,j;
char values[32]="abcd1234efgh12";
char temp[10];

for(i=0;values[i]!='\0';){
   for (j=0;j<4;j++,i++){
      temp[j]=values[i];
   }
   while(j<4)
   {
        temp[j]=' ';
   }
   temp[j]='\0';
printf("string temp:%s\n",temp);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: can anyone leave a comment explain why voting down this answer

Comment: Probably, There is a latent bugs in this program. i have noticed below. (1) `while(j<4)` This does not work. (2) values[i]!='\0' is copied beyond this place.